# Funny result with mysql comparsion

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table with a column (mail_flag) defined as tinyint value = 0

When I set up the sql-statement: `select * from table where mail_flag = "r"` I get all rows as result. Actually I expect an empty result. Has anyone a explanation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're comparing a number (`tinyint`, in this case) to a character, [MySQL will attempt to convert the character to a number.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html) Even worse, it will truncate the character string at the first non-numeric character it encounters. Here, since you have no numeric characters, the string is treated as a `0`, and, of course, `0` is equal to `0`.

In order to get a reasonable result, you should force MySQL to cast the number to a string, instead of the default casting:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  CAST(mail_flag AS CHAR(1)) = 'r'
```